# How to check whether a String contains at least one letter using JavaScript Regular Expression?

Tags: javascript, regex

In a part of my application written in **PHP**, I need to check whether a field contains at least one letter or not in **client side validation**, to do that I write the following **JavaScript Code**:

```
var name_allow_char = /^[a-zA-Z\-\'\s]+$/;
var name_allow_letter = /[A-Za-z]+$/;
if( $.trim( $('#title').val() ).match( name_allow_char ) && !$.trim( $('#title').val() ).match( name_allow_letter ) ) {
    //show error
} else {
    //ok
}
```

But it does not work. I mean when I test using **12**, it show valid, but it should be invalid as there is no letter...

Can anyone tell me what's wrong in my code.

- Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you did not swap conditions? You show error if the text matches a string consisting of letters, `-`, `'`, whitespace, and that does not end with a letter. `12` does not qualify, so it is `True`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: I may write wrong condition. I can't figure out what's wrong in my condition,

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Your logic does not make sense to me.

Comment: I have same thought with @WiktorStribiżew. so the current logic is: IF the (name has char) and (name doesn't have letter) then show error. that doesn't seems right to me.

Comment: I doubt we can help, the question is too unclear. You use two patterns with some conditions in mind you did not explain. Once you explain what exactly you want to match and what not to match, please update the question and let know.

Comment: I have made an example here https://regex101.com/r/rfliFL/2/

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Forget about what I wrote as condition, I might wrote wrong condition, so what I want is: Suppose I have an input field with id: *title* and it can accept all keyboard character as input, now I want to write a regex that will search if the title input fields length is greater than 0 than it must have at least one letter (a-z or A-Z).

Example:
1. L --> valid
2. k --> valid
3. 123423@#$ --> invalid
4. 123%^%k --> valid
5. 436AB54 --> valid
6. 3435 ^%&^ ksdka --> valid

Comment: Use `if (/^(?:[^A-Za-z]*[A-Za-z].*)?$/.test($.trim($("#title").val())) {
    // ok    
} else {
    // error
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
if ($.trim($("#title").val()).match(/([a-zA-Z])+([ -~])*/) {
    // ok    
} else {
    // error
}
```

The regex should match 1 letter or more followed by 0 or more ASCII symbols (from space to tilde)

[Demo](https://codepen.io/mathewst1/pen/xyWaKj)

Comment: Title can contain ant printable character. I mean: a-z, A-Z, 0-9, -, :, and so on..

Comment: Changed the regex, does this do what you need?

Comment: If all, you want to check, is that it contains at least one letter, you can simply use this regex: /\w/ if it return a value, then there's a letter.

Comment: But /\w/ also seems to match only numbers (alphanumeric + undescroce) and OP doesn't want that. There must be min. 1 letter.

Comment: @Mathias: Thank you very much. This is what I want Bro... :)

Comment: No problem, glad to help :)